# Weirdness on the election page - missing comments, and disqualified candidate is visible

Tags: bug, status-norepro, election

I'm using chrome on a HTC one V and noticed two odd things when attempting to view the election page

[image]

Firstly, the candidate here has been disqualified (twice?) and dosen't turn up on the non mobile page.

Secondly I see a certain lack of comments - its inconsistant, some have one, some have up to 4 and one user has 7. I suppose this might be a rendering error, but the other isn't. I'll be following up using the stock browser, but I'm wondering if anyone else can confirm this, or if its just me?

Comment: The nominations are being rigged ?! :P

Comment: Maybe there are different style sheets that determine the content displayed in a device-dependent way?

Comment: @AshRj I doubt that the elections are rigged, but I do think there is a technical problem behind this.

Comment: Good I can't even access the mobil page of the election now:(

Comment: @smartboyhw If [gertvdijk's answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6052/22949) is correct, that suggests your problem might be entirely different. Assuming you've followed the advice in it and it doesn't help, I recommend posting a separate meta question about this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### It's just you

Take a further look and you'll see that you're looking at an **older cached page**.

- "Nominations close in 7 days." That's what it said 5-6 days ago.
- "posted 7 mins ago"
- "posted 26 mins ago" Well, in fact jokerdino posted it a long time earlier.

So, just reload the web page, try clearing caches, etc.

Comment: That makes sense. Its amusing that I didn't notice that earlier, and reinforces my hatred of phone browsers ;p